# How to fix slow initial load time on asp website?

Tags: asp.net, performance, web, compilation, loading

When i use developer tools to analyze the network load times I see that my time to first byte is sometime 8 seconds long when loading the Index.aspx document.

My pages are optimized and are never greater than 1.4 megabytes in size.
I optimized my images to be below 100 kilobytes.
I precompile my website on publish.
I set debug="false" in the web.config file.

After the website has taken a long time to compile everything loads very fast.
I am using GoDaddy's shared Plesk hosting.

Comment: Hi Adam, there are several different things that might be going on which contribute to slow page loads. 1.4 mb is still pretty big for a page, but that would not be the first place that I look. What kind of processing are you doing on page load? is that page loading other external content, like a large number of images or external scripts? is it possible that those are waiting to load before the page displays? Can you give a little more specific detail on the page that is having a problem, and possibly show the html and code behind?

Comment: It doesnt matter which page, even the most simple pages with barely any content can take a long time to load. It happens whenever the site is first hit after publishing or after I haven't been to the website for some time. I think its just the website needing to compile but I wish there was a way to cut down on that compile time. @Gregor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I think I see what the problem is. ASP.NET pages need to be JIT compiled before they can render. So the first time you make a request to the server, the entire site is compiled from a CIL .NEt binary to native machine code. Once compiled that native code is cached on the server in the running app pool. If the server has no traffic for a while (generally the default is 20 minutes) then the cached native code is cleared out so the next time you hit a page, it takes a while to compile the code. This is a common issue with ASP.NET WebSites and WebForms applications. There are a few ways that you can deal with this.

1) The manual method (not ideal) - If the site only needs to be accessible during business hours you could hit the site first thing in the morning, and every request after will be quick
2) Lengthen the cache duration, but since this is hosted on GoDaddy/Plex I don't know how much control you will have over the AppPool
3) Create a light weight windows service whose sole purpose is to ping the website every 10 - 15 minutes to keep the cache alive and keep the site responsive

Option 3 feels like a little bit of a hack, but I have used that approach on many projects where the site is not constantly being hit by users throughout the day, but I wanted to make sure that no one user had a bad initial page load experience.

Comment: Interesting ideas, and yes it feels like every 20 minutes or so of inactivity the site needs to be recompiled. I should mention I also have another website hosted with Plesk that is just made up of PHP files and it appears to be doing the same thing but not as bad. I dont think PHP needs compiling like how ASP does but but I don't know if this issue is in the same category. @Gregor

Comment: I haven't worked with Plesk in quite a while so I don't know if there is also some initialization going on there when the app gets called for the first time in a while. PHP should not have the same initial lag because it is an interpreted language, so you should not have the same issues. So my initial thought would be to check with Plesk, but if it is a shared host, you wouldn't have the ability to change that anyway. In that case, I would go with an approach like option 3, both for the ASP.NEt and PHP sites to see if that helps.

Comment: The PHP site suffering the same issues is what really confuses me. I will call GoDaddy today and see if they have an idea on whats going on here. Thank you! @Gregor

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. GoDaddy's shared Plesk hosting has a fixed 5 minutes until the idle worker process shuts down. When the worker process shuts down, your website essentially goes to "sleep" and takes a long time to "wake-up" when a new visitor hits the site.

The solution is to get more traffic or to ping the website every 5 minutes to keep it running.